App looking for /sdcard path, SD card path is in /storage/<alphanumeric>
I'm trying to run an app (Einstein, the Apple Newton emulator) and it is looking for the ROM image in /sdcard/Download/Einstein, but my Samsung Galaxy Note 10+ displays the sdcard path as /storage/6E8B-161E.
Is there a way to fix this?

/sdcard is only named this way for historical reasons. AFAIR before Android 4.x the sdcard was mounted there (at that time an sd-card was mandatory). Later phones had so much flash storage that sdcard was changed to point to your internal flash, then named shared storage.  The path /storage/6E8B-161E is your real sd-card. Thus the Newton emulator is not searching on your sd-card but on your shared storage. That can only be changed by modifying the app. Contact the app developer.

As Robert has mentioned, nowadays, /sdcard refers to internal storage instead. Perhaps you could try placing the ROM file there?

I looked around and /sdcard actually does point to the card. The reason I thought that it didn't is that termius and "terminal emulator" show the directories but no files. I used Google "files" app and can confirm the files are there on the card. Is there some permission issue that doesn't let it see them?

"I looked around and /sdcard actually does point to the card." - for sure not
